# Get a string instead of a number

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

This works fine:

```
[1]> ((lambda (x) (/ x x)) 5)
1
```

but this:

```
[2]> ((lambda (x y) (/ x y)) 5 2)
5/2
```

give me '5/2' instead of 2.5. How can I fix it?

Comment: That's not a string, it's a rational number.

Comment: Could you explain it? I've just began learn this language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Common Lisp performs rational arithmetic whenever possible. If you want floating point, you either have to supplying at least one float as input to the arithmetic function, or use an explicit coercion function on the result.

```
((lambda (x y) (float (/ x y)) 5 2)
```

or

```
((lambda (x y) (/ x y)) 5.0 2)
```

Rational arithmetic is generally more exact than floating point. Consider this:

```
(setf x1 (/ 1 3)) => 1/3
(setf x2 (float (/ 1 3)) => 0.33333333
(* x1 3) => 1
(* x2 3) => 0.99999999
```